# Bamboo/grails error 2.4.4 Error Script not found: Upgrade

Tags: grails, bamboo

When I run grails war, on Bamboo, I get the following error.

13-Apr-2015 11:15:53    | Configuring classpath

13-Apr-2015 11:15:59    | Running pre-compiled script

**13-Apr-2015 11:15:59  | Error Script not found: Upgrade**

Now I know that grails upgrade command has been removed from 2.4.4 so this is the cause but why is it (Upgrade) calling it in Bamboo. I have updated grailsw and grailsw.bat to be 2.4.4 but is still calling it? My app is set to 2.4.4 (application.properties). What could be the reason it is calling this(Upgrade) and/or how do I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, being in the same boat, the grails plugin itself is calling grails upgrade before running any commands you put in there.

The way I've got this working with 2.4.4 is to use a command instead of the build-in grails task.

My command simply maps to C:\grails\grails-2.4.4\bin\grails.bat and I just pass it command line args: -Dgrails.env=alpha war myApp-alpha.war

It's not as seamless doing multiple commands (like, clean -> test-app -> war), but you can do individual commands for each one, depending on the needs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, its a Bamboo plugin for Grails has some bug.
For work around:
You! Could have added dummy upgrade script into your code.
For adding upgrade script:

```
grails create-script upgrade
```

After adding upgrade script, it will fix missing upgrade script issue on Bamboo.

Comment: Unfortunately not,                                                                                      Got: Created file scripts/Upgrade.groovy     
| Created file test/cli/UpgradeTests.groovy         ....but same error